# What is tkinter askdirectory default value for initialdir parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have an entry widget and a button that calls askdirectory. I would like the initial value for the entry widget to be the default initialdir parameter for askdirectory. How do I get that value from the askdirectory function? (the reason I want to do this and not set an initial parameter is that I suspect that the function saves a recent directory and I would like to help the user save some time looking for the directory)

Answer (score 1):

The default is the current working directory.

From the canonical tk documentation about the `initialdir` option:

> Specifies that the directories in *directory* should be displayed when the dialog pops up. If this parameter is not specified, then the directories in the current working directory are displayed. If the parameter specifies a relative path, the return value will convert the relative path to an absolute path.

That being said, the dialogs on OSX and Windows are native dialogs, and there might be platform-specific behavior to pick your home directory or last used directory or most recently used directory. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to get that information.

Comment: I read that and compared os.getcwd() with the directory that askdirectory opens and is definetely not the same. The first contains my python code, the second does not have any python code. As I mentioned, it was like it saved the last browsed directory using a dialog like this.

Comment: @DIANACAROLINADUQUEMONTOYA: since the dialogs are native OS dialogs (on windows and OSX), it may very well be that the OS remembers the previous or most common location.